# How do I power up the radio transmitter?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm on the "Taking Independence" mission with the Minutemen and now I need to power the radio transmitter. I already built a generator, but that doesn't seem to be enough, I need to connect it somehow.

How exactly do I connect the generator to the transmitter? The various electricity items I can build in the Workshop aren't really explained.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Step by Step, no pics

1. Build a small generator (skip if you have an existing with spare power)
2. While in workshop mode still, press <kbd>SPACE</kbd> (Y on XB, Triangle on PS4) while highlighting the generator. (it should now show a little wire from generator to your cursor that moves around with you)
3. Highlight the Radio Tower, and press <kbd>SPACE</kbd>(Y on XB, Triangle on PS4) again.

Bam! Transmission begins.

Comment: It's Y on Xbox, and I'd assume triangle on PS.

Comment: Yes, to confirm, it is triangle on the PS.

Comment: Might be worth noting that the generator is not the only existing item in the base in need of power. There's an industrial water purifier and light bulbs as well.

Comment: The radio transmitter requires 10 power, so the small generator isn't sufficient. There's a video on [an answer to a duplicate of this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/307640/108003) that shows the power requirement, at right about 1:30.

Answer (score 7):

You build a generator and then power cables from the generator to the radio.

[image: connecting the radio tower]

You create wires by pointing at an electrical object and pressing the button highlighted for Attach Wire:

[image: attach wire]

Answer (score 2):

In order to link your generator to other objects, you must first target the generator in build mode.  When you press `space` (assuming you are playing on a PC - I am unsure what the console equivalent is), you will start dragging a wire.  With the wire in hand, target the object you want to power - in this case, the radio transmitter.  When you press `space` (or the console equivalent) again, the wire will now run between the objects.  You're done!

Note that you need a clear line of sight between the generator and the object that you are powering.