# Fallout 4 powering up radio transmitter

Tags: fallout-4

I am doing a minuteman quest name Taking Independence and it wants me to power up a radio transmitter. I built a small generator and attached the cables, but it doesn't seem to work. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

The radio transmitter requires 10 power to turn it on.  A small generator only produces 3.  You will need 7 more power to turn on the transmitter.  Either build 3 more small generators and attach them all together, or build a different type of power source.  As long as the total power reaches 10, you will have enough.  After you have enough power, activate the controls to turn on the transmitter.

Video for reference: